# what does the sentence "I'd hate for anything to come between us" means?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of the sentence **"I'd hate for anything to come between us"**?
After knowing the meaning of used phrasal verbs and all that, I can get a good enough idea of its meaning. But,I am, however, finding the structure of the sentence a bit weird.

Comment: A more conventional version would be "I'd hate _it if anything were to_ come between us".

Answer (score 2):

> "I'd hate for anything to come between us"

is grammatically correct and uses an idiom in its figurative sense:

**come between (someone and someone else)**.   [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+between+us)

> - Lit. to be in between two people.
> - Fig. to interfere in someone else's romance; to break up a pair of    lovers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd hate for anything to come between us = I don't want us to have a disagreement over something. That "something" would come between us and separate us.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence means the same if you simply omit *for*:

- I'd hate anything to come between us.

The *Oxford Modern English Grammar* (p82) notes that this sentence structure with the omissible *for* is more common in American English:

> Finally, we recognize *for* as a subordinating conjunction in clauses
>   that do not carry tense, as in (171) . This construction is more
>   frequent in American English.
>
> - 171 There is nothing I want [<sub>clause</sub>  *for* you to say
>     anyway].